# Detect the id of server control on master page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, adrotator

I have an `adrotator` on my Asp.net Master Page

```
<asp:AdRotator ID="adr" AdvertisementFile="~/Adrotator.xml" Width="180px" Height="200px"
                 runat="server" Target="_self" />
```

I am using the following jquery for rotating ADS . However it is not able to detect the id of the Adrotator control

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

            setInterval(function () {
            $("[id$='adr']").load(location.href + "[id$='adr']", "" + Math.random() + "");
        }, 5000);

    });
```

Note: I already tried using `$("[id$='adr']")` and `$('[id$=\'adr\']')` and `'#adr'`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
 $('#<%=adr.ClientID%>').Load.....
```

in asp.net code, use this id selectors: `$("#<%= adr.ClientID %>").Load...;` for server controls as client id may be changed by asp.net infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("[id$='<%=adr.ClientID %>']")
```

- [See ClientID mode for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the generated html source of the ad rotator. This could give you more insight into how you should write your jQuery.

Comment: <a id="adr" target="_self"><img src="/ChildVaccinationSystem/Images/word.png" alt="Dr gulati" style="height:200px;width:180px;" /></a>

Comment: So that means it does detect the id but the adrotator jquery isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use

```
<asp:AdRotator ID="adr" AdvertisementFile="~/Adrotator.xml" Width="180px" Height="200px"
             runat="server" Target="_self" CssClass="adr" />
```

and class selector

```
$(".adr")
```

Or you may use databind

```
$("#<%# adr.ClientID %>")
```

and

```
Databind();
```

on page load.